# Skiing questions: travel.SE or outdoors.SE?

Tags: discussion

This is not really a question, but I don't know a better way to draw community attention in the Stack Exchange framework.

Over on meta.travel.SE I have [asked a question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/969/2509) about whether skiing questions belong over there or here, based on what properties of the question. To avoid duplicate discussions, I propose we join with them to define how to determine what skiing questions best belong on Travel.SE and which ones best belong here.

Answer (score 4):

We definitely allow skiing questions here, in terms of techniques and such.  Like how to cut a slope or snow conditions or etc to avoid...

Comment: Yeah, I was actually considering to propose migrating one or more skiing questions at Travel.SE to here.